# How to find how many times a code was used in the past 5 years

Tags: oracle

I'm looking to see often account codes (FTABLE_ACCT_CODE) from a list were used in the past 5 years. I'd like to inactivate them if they weren't used much.

I tried the following

```
select distinct FTABLE_ACCT_CODE, Count(FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE), FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE
from FTable
where FTABLE_ACCT_CODE IN ('1000','1001')
and FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE >= '15-May-2018'
GROUP BY FTABLE_ACCT_CODE, FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE
```

I was expecting only 1 row per ACCT_CODE saying when & how many times it was last used in the past 5 years. But my code shows over 70 rows and every single time the ACCT_CODE was used in the past 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both the distinct and the group by.
Also including the date is going to cause you problems. Try again as follows

```
select FTABLE_ACCT_CODE, Count(FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE)
from FTable
where FTABLE_ACCT_CODE IN ('1000','1001')
and FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE >= '15-May-2018'
GROUP BY FTABLE_ACCT_CODE
```

Not sure whether this also has meaning for you but I thought worth mentioning that count(FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE) can have a different result than count(*) if there are null date values in some rows. count(*) returns the count of rows, whereas count(FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE) returns the count of rows in which FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to group by the date, only the account code.  You don't want dates in the resulting rows.

```
select FTABLE_ACCT_CODE, Count(FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE)
from FTable
where FTABLE_ACCT_CODE IN ('1000','1001')
and FTABLE_ACTIVITY_DATE >= '15-May-2018'
group by FTABLE_ACCT_CODE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code, which you ran (and were already suggested) works *today*, but tomorrow (and the day after tomorrow, and ...) won't work any longer because you're comparing

- `ftable_activity_date` to a *constant* ...
- ... which is (to make things worse) a **string**

For the first issue, consider referring to `sysdate`; it returns both date and time, so you might even want to truncate it (i.e. set it to midnight). Additionally, use `add_months` function and *subtract* 60 months (12 months * 5 years). It should work OK for any dates, take care about leap years and such things.

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate),
  2    add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12 * 5)
  3  from dual;

TRUNC(SYSD ADD_MONTHS
---------- ----------
16.05.2023 16.05.2018

SQL>
```

For the second issue, `'15-May-2018'` is a string and you're relying on Oracle's capabilities of implicit datatype conversion. Sometimes it'll succeed, sometimes not. For example, your code - in my database (and in yours, if NLS change) - won't work:

```
SQL> select * from emp where hiredate > '15-May-2018';
select * from emp where hiredate > '15-May-2018'
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

So, if you want to compare activity date to a *constant*, then either use date literal (which consists of the `date` keyword followed by date value enclosed into single quotes, following the `yyyy-mm-dd` format), or `to_date` function with appropriate format model and - optionally - NLS clause, if you'll be passing month name. These would work, always & everywhere:

```
ftable_activity_date >= date '2018-05-15'
ftable_activity_date >= to_date('15-May-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')
ftable_activity_date >= to_date('15.05.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

So: code which you might be interested in would then be

```
select ftable_acct_code, 
       count(ftable_activity_date) cnt
from ftable
where ftable_acct_code in ('1000', '1001')
  and ftable_activity_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12 * 5)
group by ftable_acct_code;
```